# How to conditionally count on a sub-aggregate

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

There are several questions on Stack Overflow which deal with a straight forward case of a conditional count, e.g.:

```
Name  Amount
A     10
B     0
```

Where you want to know how many names have a non zero amount. But my use case is a bit different. I have a table like this:

```
Category  Name  Amount
Top       A     10
Top       A     -5
Top       B     10
Top       B     -10
```

Now I want a result that would look like this:

```
Category   NameCount
Top        1
```

Because the Sum of Amount for A is 5, but for B is 0, so only A would count.

How can this be accomplished in an expression? Subqueries aren't helpful in my case (I would know how to do it with a sub query).

Comment: Why aren't sub-queries helpful? Since they easily provide a solution it seems like they'd be quite helpful.

Comment: @HartCO, the nature of how the query is constructed (through an ad-hoc reporting tool) don't allow for them. I could just write the query (sub query and all) and report on that, but I'm looking to see if there is a way without resorting to that, so it can be done in several different contexts using this kind of tool.

Comment: not sure why people down vote. this is a good question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using a sub-query or a `CTE` pretty easily:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  Category, Name, Sum(Amount) As TotalAmount
    From    YourTable
    Group by Category, Name
    Having Sum(Amount) <> 0
)
Select  Category, Count(Distinct Name) AS NameCount
From    Cte
Group By Category
```

Comment: Thanks, but I said at the end of the question "Subqueries aren't helpful in my case" CTE's aren't better.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT Category,Name,SUM( Amount ) AS SumVal
   INTO #Categories
   FROM Yourtable
  GROUP BY Category, Name;

 SELECT Category, SUM( CASE WHEN SumVal <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS NameCount
   FROM #Categories
 GROUP BY Category;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I said at the end of the question "Subqueries aren't helpful in my case"

Comment: If subqueries dont work for u then u can try using temp tables as above.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of the question here, you want to aggregate twice on the same data-set, at different granularities (while applying some filters in the middle).
Without using some form of sub-query (temp table, cte, etc) it would not be possible to perform this kind of an operation, since the group by condition can be applied only at a single granularity in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Simply aggregate in subquery to find category and name with non zero total and then find count of distinct name in each category:

```
select
    category,
    count(name) namecount
from (
    select
        category,
        name
    from your_table t
    group by category, name
    having sum(amount) <> 0
) t group by category;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I said at the end of the question "Subqueries aren't helpful in my case"